# Trying to add POST data to a string

Tags: php, forms, email, post

So I have some PHP and I am trying to bring over some data from a previous page's form and make them output within this <<

```
$firstname = echo $_POST["firstname"];
$email = echo $_POST["email"];

$data = <<<STRING
<contact>
<Group_Tag name="Contact Information">
<field name="First Name">$firstname</field>
<field name="E-Mail">$email</field>
</Group_Tag>
</contact>
STRING;
```

Comment: Remove echo: `$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$firstname = echo $_POST["firstname"];
```

What black magic are you trying to achieve here?!

Leave that ugly echo keyword out here. You are assigning a variable. Not assigning a result from echo…

```
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
```

Comment: I was trying to pre-populate the details in that string with info entered from a form on the previous page... It worked!

Comment: @ForestParks then please accept the answer by clicking on the green bordered tick on the left of my question :-)

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
 $firstname = echo $_POST["firstname"];
```

with

```
 echo $firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try this option because the answer above worked.